# Clapping in meetings

Tags: work-environment, meetings

Company got bought a while back. Some new head of something comes visit from oversea. All hands meeting. At the end of the meeting the local office boss thanks the bigger boss for coming over and starts clapping. Next thing everyone starts clapping. Nobody really knows why. I'm not clapping, I just feel awkward.

<s>Should I do something about it? If so what?</s>

Goal: I'd like other people to realise there is nothing to celebrate in this situation.

Idea (reductio ad absudrum): start clapping randomly when someone important finishes a sentence. Wait for other clappers to join in. Ask why they clapping. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: I'd include the countries where this takes place and where the other boss is from to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Clapping is a social convention, and social conventions will vary at the highest level across cultures, and at the lowest level within individual groups.  It is possible that you have been bought by a company where the convention is to applaud the bigger boss.  Plus, it is also possible that your local boss is trying to improve his social standing with the visiting higher boss.

You can decide whether you want to join in with this convention, but if you don't and the majority does, you are going to stand out - you won't be in the "in group".  You need to decide personally if you care about this, and your decision should include considerations of what sanctions may be imposed - which could range from mild disapproval all the way through to being fired for "showing disrespect".